# A Functional Derivative calculation

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, derivatives

Is there anyway to calculate below functional derivative?

$\delta \textbf{G}/ \delta_{p_\alpha} = ?$

$\textbf{G} = \int dr^3 [a |\nabla \cdot p|^2+c \nabla \cdot p]$

integral is in 3D. Could some one please help me? I don't know what to do with divergence. I have find an example in wikipedia but there is only gradinent(no divergence)

Answer (score 0):

We have the nonlinear functional 
$$\textbf{G}[p] = \int dr^3 \left( a \, \left(\nabla \cdot p\right)^2 + c \, \nabla \cdot p \right)$$

The functional derivative is given by the term linear in $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^3, \mathbb R^3)$ of the expansion of 
$$\begin{align}
\textbf{G}[p+\phi] 
& = \int dr^3 \left( a \, \left(\nabla \cdot (p+\phi)\right)^2 + c \, \nabla \cdot (p+\phi) \right) \\
& = \int dr^3 \left( a \, \left( (\nabla \cdot p)^2 + 2 (\nabla \cdot p) (\nabla \cdot \phi) + (\nabla \cdot \phi)^2 \right) + c \, \nabla \cdot p + c \, \nabla \cdot \phi) \right) \\
& = \int dr^3 \left( a \, \left(\nabla \cdot p\right)^2 + c \, \nabla \cdot p \right) + \int dr^3 \left( 2 a (\nabla \cdot p)(\nabla \cdot \phi) + c \nabla \cdot \phi \right) + \int dr^3 \, a (\nabla \cdot \phi)^2
\\
& = G[p] + \langle \delta G[p], \phi \rangle  + O(\phi^2)
\end{align}$$

Thus,
$$\begin{align}
\langle \delta G[p], \phi \rangle
& = \int dr^3 \left( 2 (\nabla \cdot p)(\nabla \cdot \phi) + c \nabla \cdot \phi \right) \\
& = 2 \int dr^3 (\nabla \cdot p)(\nabla \cdot \phi)
+ c \int dr^3 \, \nabla \cdot \phi
\end{align}$$

Here the first term can be partially integrated giving
$$2 \int dr^3 (\nabla \cdot p)(\nabla \cdot \phi)
= -2 \int dr^3 \, \nabla (\nabla \cdot p) \cdot \phi$$

The second term vanishes:
$$c \int dr^3 \, \nabla \cdot \phi = c \oint \phi \cdot dS = 0$$
since $\phi$ vanishes for a large radius.

Thus,
$$\delta G[p] = -2 \, \nabla (\nabla \cdot p)$$

Comment: Which terms are added if add $\int |\hat{z} \times \nabla \times \delta p|^2 d^3x$ to G function?

Comment: p is a vector in direction perpendicular to $\hat{z}$

Comment: What is $\delta$ in front of $p$? A constant or some kind of operator?